# Exclude files with no extension with robocopy?

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I'm new to Powershell (as of this morning). I have put together this script (directories reflect local testing):

```
$Destinations = Get-Content "C:\PowerShellConfigFiles\destinationPaths.txt"
$Source = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\PowerShellConfigFiles\sourcePath.txt")
$ExcludeFiles = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\PowerShellConfigFiles\xf.txt")
$ExcludeDirectories = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\PowerShellConfigFiles\xd.txt")

foreach($Destination in $Destinations)
{
    robocopy $Source $Destination /E /xf $ExcludeFiles /xd $ExcludeDirectories
}
```

In my `ExcludeFiles` I have a couple extensions such as `.xlsx`.  I also want to exclude files that do not have any extension at all. I haven't been able to find a way to do this with the `/xf` option. Can this be done, or do I need to explore another approach to handle exluding files with no extension?

Comment: Sorry for my earlier answer. I was too hasty and misread your question. I just posted one that does what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter a listing of files in **$Source** with a regex to get a list of files without extensions, and add that list to **$ExcludeFiles**. Replace `/xf $ExcludeFiles` with this:

```powershell
/xf ($ExcludeFiles + (Get-ChildItem -File $Source -Name | ?{$_ -notmatch '\.'}))
```

For compatibility with versions of PowerShell lower than 3.0, which don't support the **-File** switch for **Get-ChildItem**, use this instead:

```powershell
/xf ($ExcludeFiles + (Get-ChildItem $Source | ?{! $_.PSIsContainer} | select -ExpandProperty Name | ?{$_ -notmatch '\.'}))
```

By definition, a file with an extension is a file with a dot in the name, so `$_ -notmatch '\.'` selects only names without extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I used /xf *.? and it seemed to have worked.
It also missed all the files with single letter extension, but I didn't have any of those i cared about :-)